# How to add Discount for a Product base on Quantity

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, price-rules

I was tried to add Product rules but didn't worked. 
This is what I tried to do.

**Ex: I have 4 products named A,B,C,D. I want to give 50% discount for B product if someone buy more than 2 qty of B product.**

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: @ Amal Madawa , I have posted an answer here, please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I have verified my solution in my local instance M2.2.0 and found working great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding Customer Group price for your particular products.

Example: Edit product B => Advanced Pricing => Customer Group Price => Add.
Provide the website as All websites and Customer Group as ALL GROUPS. You can select these values as per your requirement and then, provide quantity as 2 and Price as discount with value 50%.

[image]

Clear cache and check your product.

Comment: If he uses Magento 2.1 or 2.0, he will need an extension for this. (Because the percent discount in tier prices is only available on Magento 2.2). One of the extensions that implement this functionality is https://www.mexbs.com/dynamic-tier-magento2-extension. Disclamer: I am the CEO of the company that developed the extension.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a new cart price rule. Go to **Admin -> Marketting -> Cart price rule** and create new rule as define here condition and action as per below screenshot:

In condition tab:

[image]

and in action tab:

[image]