# How to apply discount per item?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Magento is giving a discount which applies in the total and another method which is applying the custom price. I don't want to change the price. I just want to change in the subtotal and total price. Does anyone have any solution for this?

Comment: Can you add screenshots to better describe what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Please can u Refer below link "to add Discount for a Product base on Quantity"

> [How to add Discount for a Product base on Quantity](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198768/how-to-add-discount-for-a-product-base-on-quantity)

There are various options to Achieve this,

**a.** You can achieve this by adding Customer Group price on products.

For Example In Admin side Please edit Product and Price Like this:

> Edit product >> Advanced Pricing >> Customer Group Price >> Add

Select the website as All websites and Customer Group as ALL GROUPS. You can select these values as per your requirement and then, provide quantity as 2 and Price as discount with value 50%.

**b.** Using Cart Price Rule with product SKU conditions

**c.** Customize to give custom discount on products attribute level.

Thanks!!