# Magento2: Cart rule not working properly

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping-cart

I go to Magento 2 *Admin > Marketing > Promotions > Cart Price Rules* and create a new Rule: Rule1:

Tab Rule Information:

- Rule Name: Rule1
- Status: Active
- Websites: Main Website
- Customer Groups: select all
- Coupon: No Coupon
- Uses per Customer: 0
- From: blank
- To: blank
- Priority: 0
- Public in RSS Feed: No

Conditions tab:

- If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :

  - If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true:

    - Manufacturer  is  Adidas

Actions Tab:

- Apply: percent of product price discount
- Discount Amount: 10
- Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To: 0
- Discount Qty Step (Buy X): 0
- Apply to Shipping Amount: No
- Discard subsequent rules: No
- Free Shipping: No
- Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items): nothing

Then I have assigned Adidas Manufacturer to "Sneakers" product and Nike to "Test Product5" product.

Add "Sneakers" product to cart and see it showing 10% discount in Order Summary because rule match with the condition.

Then added the "Test Product5" in the cart, which shows a 20% discount in the Order Summary that is wrong because only the "Sneakers" product matched with the condition and "Test Product5" product not matched with the cart rule condition.

[image]

The product that matching the rule in the cart individually:-
[image]

The product that not matching the rule in the cart individually:-
[image]

Please give me an advice. How can make a discount on each item in Magento 2.2.6?

Comment: See accepted answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198768/how-to-add-discount-for-a-product-base-on-quantity

Comment: above answer not working for me, please let me know other solution

Answer (score 1):

The rule is working correctly as per the configuration.
Conditions tab:
If ALL of these conditions are TRUE :
If an item is FOUND in the cart with ALL of these conditions true:
Manufacturer is Adidas

This rule says if there is any item in the cart with the manufacturer as Adidas, then apply 10% discount to the whole cart and not just to the specific product.

If you want to apply the discount to the specific items, then you have to add the condition under 'Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions'.